# Windows could not start the service on Local Computer. Error 193: 0xc1

Tags: python, system-services

I coded a python a program and converted it to an executable. It was working perfectly. Then I used sc.exe in cmd to make it a system service. But the problem is that when I try to start the service, [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXa7T.png) pops up. By searching online, I came to know that the path to that exe file might be incorrect, but that's not the case with me.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is no connection between .exe and service. That's why can't start. What kind of program is that? If is for network you have duplicated port.

Have fun!!!

Comment: it is a keylogger to monitor the employees. I want it to run in the background as a service